# How to display preformatted data in headings?

Tags: html, pre

I am new to HTML. I was trying the following code to work but it did not. Can anyone please help me out why `<pre> tag` is not working inside `<h> tags`? I also tried to code tag but it din't worked too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
        <head>
                <title> Checking Different Headings | Isnt it fun?</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>  This is a title</h1>
                <h2>  What is life? </h2>
                <h3>  Paragraphs are written using <pre> <p></pre>tags </h3>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pre` element is not what you want there.

If you are trying to show `<p>`, you should use `&lt;p&gt;`.

The HTML angle brackets (less and greater than characters) are encoded, so they are no longer meaningful in HTML tags.

Otherwise, the HTML parser believes your `<p>` is a `p` element.

Comment: So I should use the blackquote option from DreamWeaver. Thanks. This should get the job done

Comment: @JustAnotherProgrammer: I'm not familiar with DreamWeaver sorry.

Comment: @JustAnotherProgrammer: `&lt;` is the HTML entity for `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
        <head>
                <title> Checking Different Headings | Isnt it fun?</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>  This is a title</h1>
                <h2>  What is life? </h2>
                <h3>  Paragraphs are written using </h3> <pre> <p></pre> <h3>tags </h3>
        </body>
</html>
```

However, the contents in the `<pre>` tag will not be shown inline with `<h3>` also, it wont match the font size. You may want to use CSS to change how to display the `<pre>` tag with `<h3>`

Comment: @Just: Sorry, you are right. I should have tried it before posting. :-( Well, OP, html entities are the right way to go. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp